# ajax call not reset old data

Tags: ajax, jquery

I am using the ajax in my website, it is working fine but it not success data on next call, I mean if on first call, data is 1 and 0 and on second call data is 0 and 1, then it is showing on 2nd call 1, 0, 0, 1

```
function checkform(){
var userid = $("#userid").val();
var email = $("#email").val();
$.ajax({
    url:path+"ajax_getpass.php",
    data:{userid : userid, email : email},
    cache:'false',
    type:'POST',
    dataType:"json",
    success: function(data_send){
        $(document).ajaxComplete(function(event, request) {
            //data = $.parseJSON(data);
            alert(data_send.email);
            alert(data_send.userid);
        });
    }
});
return false;
}
```

please tell me where i am wrong.

Comment: Do not bind to the ajax complete event inside the success callback. That makes absolutely no sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you add more and more functions to `ajaxComplete()` every time the AJAX request is successful. So when your success code is called the first time, one function is called by `ajaxComplete()`. With the next request, another function is added, so two functions will be called.

Use this code instead:

```
$.ajax({
    url:path+"ajax_getpass.php",
    data:{userid : userid, email : email},
    cache:'false',
    type:'POST',
    dataType:"json",
    success: function(data_send){
        alert(data_send.email);
        alert(data_send.userid);
    }
});
```

You only need `$.ajaxComplete()` when you want to respond to AJAX requests sent by some other part of the code (i.e. in places where you can't specify the success function).

Think of it as a kind of global "success" function.

Comment: but I need some more validation in the function

Comment: @Mani the ajax complete method isn't the way to do that.

Comment: @KevinB So what I should do for this

Comment: @Mani: So? Just add it to the `success` function directly.